# Shopware 6 Administration Error 'The String is not a valid UUID'

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I am trying to insert data into a custom entity via the administration.
I generated the UUID via `Utils.createId()` function.
If I insert data without the id, everything works perfectly, but when I insert data along with my own generated Id, I get the error

`'FRAMEWORK__WRITE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION', status: '400', detail: 'The string "018A41183FDB7460896E02F5F3EE7D8E" is not a valid uuid.', template: 'The string "{{ stri`

Answer (score 2):

The UUID format was [recently changed to `v7`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/58344d5e8819c2b024c454db784545bed4258b7f).

Update the dependencies and re-build the administration.

Depending on your setup either run

```
composer init:js
composer build:js:admin
```

or

```
./bin/build-administration.sh
```